# Starting a new process from an asyncio loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, cryptofeed

I want to start a new Process (`Pricefeed`) from my `Executor` class and then have the Executor class keep running in its own event loop (the `shoot` method).  In my current attempt, the `asyncio` loop gets blocked on the line `p.join()`.  However, without that line, my code just exits.  How do I do this properly?

Note: `fh.run()` blocks as well.

```
import asyncio

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from cryptofeed import FeedHandler
from cryptofeed.defines import L2_BOOK
from cryptofeed.exchanges.ftx import FTX


class Pricefeed(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue: Queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.coin_symbol = 'SOL-USD'
        self.fut_symbol = 'SOL-USD-PERP'
        self.queue = queue

    async def _book_update(self, feed, symbol, book, timestamp, receipt_timestamp):
        self.queue.put(book)

    def run(self):
        fh = FeedHandler()
        fh.add_feed(FTX(symbols=[self.fut_symbol, self.coin_symbol], channels=[L2_BOOK],
                        callbacks={L2_BOOK: self._book_update}))
        fh.run()


class Executor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = Queue()

    async def shoot(self):
        print('in shoot')

        for i in range(5):
            msg = self.q.get()
            print(msg)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # do some stuff

    async def run(self):
        asyncio.create_task(self.shoot())

        p = Pricefeed(self.q)
        p.start()
        p.join()


async def main():
    g = Executor()
    await g.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: @user56700 It's inside `Pricefeed.run()`

Comment: I'm getting: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptofeed.exchange.ftx'; 'cryptofeed.exchange' is not a package` when i try to run your program.

Comment: Found `FTX` in `from cryptofeed.exchanges.ftx import FTX`, was just missing a `s` at the end.

Comment: Now i'm getting `KeyError: 'SOL-PERP' cryptofeed.exceptions.UnsupportedSymbol: SOL-PERP is not supported on FTX`. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @user56700 What version cryptofeed are u on?  I'm on `1.9.0`.  I think there may have been some breaking changes

Comment: @user56700 I just changed my code.  Now it works with `1.9.3`

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using a queue to communicate this is a somewhat tricky problem. To answer your first question as to why removing `join` makes the program work, `join` blocks until the process finishes. In asyncio you can't do *anything* blocking in a function marked `async` or it will freeze the event loop. To do this properly you'll need to run your process with the asyncio event loop's `run_in_executor` method which will run things in a process pool and return an awaitable that is compatible with the asyncio event loop.

Secondly, you'll need to use a multiprocessing `Manager` which creates shared state that can be used by multiple processes to properly share your queue. Managers directly support creation of a shared queue. Using these two bits of knowledge you can adapt your code to something like the following which works:

```
import asyncio
import functools
import time
from multiprocessing import Manager
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def run_pricefeed(queue):
    i = 0
    while True: #simulate putting an item on the queue every 250ms
        queue.put(f'test-{i}')
        i += 1
        time.sleep(.25)


class Executor:

    async def shoot(self, queue):
        print('in shoot')

        for i in range(5):
            while not queue.empty():
                msg = queue.get(block=False)
                print(msg)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # do some stuff

    async def run(self):
        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
            with Manager() as manager:
                queue = manager.Queue()
                asyncio.create_task(self.shoot(queue))
                await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(pool, functools.partial(run_pricefeed, queue))


async def main():
    g = Executor()
    await g.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This code has a drawback in that you need to empty the queue in a non-blocking fashing from your asyncio process and wait for a while for new items to come in before emptying it again, effectively implementing a polling mechanism. If you don't wait after emptying, you'll wind up with blocking code and you will freeze the event loop again. This isn't as good as just waiting for the queue to have an item in it by blocking, but may suit your needs. If possible, I would avoid asyncio here and use multiprocessing entirely, for example, by implementing queue processing as a separate process.